# Link a cell in workbook 1 to an workbook that don't exist yet

Tags: excel

I have a "workbook 1" to consolidate monthly data from others workbooks. So I have the "workbook 1" linking to others workbooks, "Jan", "Fev", "Mar"...
I need to have links for the full year in my "workbook 1", but as the monthly workbooks were not all created yet, because will be created in the future, I cannot set those links.

Do you know any workaround to set links in my "workbook 1" to others workbooks that don't exist yet?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of Indirect function. It should solve your problem but It only works if the source files are open. The moment you close your source files and try to refresh the data, you get error.

The other solution (a very good one in my opinion) is to use power query to consolidate your monthly data.

Comment: Hi ram Singh,

Thanks for the answer.
About indirect: I know it works, but as I need to have the others workbook opened that's not an opion.

About Power Query: the problem is that source files haven't a good structure to handle in power query.